# Set NetBeans hints to warn when returning Integer by method with int signature

Tags: java, netbeans, methods, integer, int

I had a serious bug in my code, which luckily I found :), because I forgot to change the method's return type signature (from int to Integer) and my app was crashing without any warning.

I had the following method:

```
public static int getDataSourceIdForName(String name) {
    Integer i = dsNameToIdMap.get(name);
    return i;
}
```

It was crashing my app. I observed that it was crashing only when a special case occurred and the `name` was actually not in the map (`Map<String, Integer> dsNameToIdMap = new HashMap<>()`) thus it was returning null. I would expect a running application to throw a `NullPointerException` but this was not the case and the app was simply dying and I had a trip full of excitement to find the bug :)

Since I would like to have my IDE's support in avoiding those situations in future, I am asking you guys **how to set `NetBeans` to warn of those situations, i.e. when I am returning an object in a function which return signature is a primitive type,** as I cannot figure it out myself.

**UPDATE:**
I have found the real problem. The code is in fact throwing the `NullPointerException`, as Jon rightly argued :) It was only my clients 'survival mechanism' that was hiding it, as you can see in the sample below:

```
public class WhyNoNullPointerException {
    private static int test() {
        Integer i = null;
        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    System.out.println("i = " + i);
                    if (i == 10) {
                        try{
                           test();
                        }finally{
                            run();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(1111);
    }
}
```

Since the program in finally tries to stay alive by restarting its main operational loop, for this reason it 'hides' the `NullPointerException`.

To avoid this situation in future I will now always, in this self restarting code, add a catch for Exception before the finally block as a good practice this way an exception will not be 'lost' (I had the block in the first place in my code I had a byte reading there which can throw `IOException`).

As to development of a hint I found a very nice tutorial over which I will go today and hopefully will have a working hint (link below). Thanks for your links guys (@JonSkeet and @Nambari) they were very useful in finding some more about the hint development.

[NetBeans Java Hint Module Tutorial.](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-java-hint.html)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that code *would* just throw a NullPointerException... what are you suggesting it did instead?

Comment: May be you need to write a new hint and import.

Comment: @JonSkeet I would expect a NullPointerException myself thought it was not the case. I will try to build a simple test case to prove it to you :)

Comment: @Nambari could you please link me to sources which would tell me how to do it?

Comment: @Boro: I've added a simple test case to prove that it *does* throw a NullPointerException. I suspect the problem isn't where you think it was, or the exception is being caught and transformed somewhere.

Comment: http://netbeans.dzone.com/news/how-create-hint-netbeans-java-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really *does* throw `NullPointerException`:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    private static final Map<String, Integer> map
        = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getInt("Foo");
    }

    public static int getInt(String name) {
        Integer i = map.get(name);
        return i;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
c:\Users\Jon\Test>java Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Test.getInt(Test.java:13)
        at Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

Now you may or may not *also* want NetBeans to warn on auto-unboxing... but it's worth at least checking what's going on first :)

I found a [plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=4130) which highlights auto-boxing/unboxing and varargs, but it's very old and may well not be supported on the version you're using.

I'd *expect* this to be configurable as a compiler option (it is in Eclipse) but I don't have enough experience with NetBeans to say much more.

Comment: You are right (+1) and I did my sample as well to see that it does in fact occur as it should :) I must look into the `logback.xml` then but I do get any other sort of exceptions it was just this one? Though it would still be lovely to have NetBeans warn me of those situations.

Comment: @Boro: I don't know enough about what you're doing to comment on why you didn't see the exception. I don't know much about NetBeans, but this plugin may help: http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=4130

Comment: Thanks guys for all. Let me look into it and when I have a `NetBeans` solution I will share it here. It is captured fine if I explicitly capture it in try-catch. So it is thrown but for some reason it is never printed out on the console, why?!

Comment: No worries @Jon. I cannot figure out what is `hiding` debugger also didn't show this exception and I have no try catch blocks around that code. Anyway I will try to isolate it and replicate it tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks all. As per my UPDATE I consider the problem solved. Though developing the plugin is more difficult then I thought particularly for someone new to NetBenas plugins. I anyone will come accross one please do share it with me. Thanks again guys (@Jon and @Nambari).